# Rails autocomplete jquery using loopj tokenizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, haml, loopj

I found the following plugin very useful but for the life of me I can't figure out how to put the submit button and the text_field on the same line.

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

here's the code that I have below:

```
.row{style: 'text-align:center;'}
  .span4.offset4
    - # only allow to post when it's the current user's account
    - if current_user
      = text_field_tag 'search-box'
      = submit_tag "Run Bitelist Sync", class: 'btn btn-primary', :style => 'height:40px;'
```

I tried floating the text_field left and the submit_tag right on while getting rid of the break, but that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, drop the %br/, that adds a linebreak.

Comment: i dropped the break and it still isn't working

Comment: More likely a css thing. Use your browser's webinspector if the inputs have an `clear:both` or `display:block` on them